# How do I change the dimensions of an object without affecting the dimensions of an interior window?

Tags: objects, transforms, geometry, dimensions

I have a rectangular object that measures 265.3m wide x 74m tall. That rectangle has a window cutout within it that is 51m wide by 40m tall. I am trying to resize the 265.3m width of the rectangle to about 75m. However, when I change the X dimension (under Options > Transform) the size of that window shrinks in width as well. How do I change the width of the rectangle without changing the dimensions of the interior window cutout?

Comment: Oh, it looks like the interior window dimensions are still 51m x 40m but why does it appear smaller???? Or, maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Are these different objects or part of the same object? If different objects, is one parent of the other?

Comment: Why the window appears smaller although it is still 51 × 40 m: If you scale an object in _Object Mode_, it is changing the outward appearance so to say... the underlying mesh is still keeping it's original size. Also the other wall is still 265.3 m in _Edit Mode_, although it is now maybe 75 m in _Object Mode_. To let the new scaled down size become its "original" size that will also show in _Edit Mode_, you have to apply the scale, i.e. so that it stays 75 m but the scale values now show 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the wall to get smaller and the window cutout to stay the same - and I assume from your question, the cutout is not done with a *Boolean* modifier using a spearate object for the size of the cutout - then you have to do it in *Edit Mode*.

There are different methods to achieve this goal, at least five which I will show you here:

1. Moving the outer vertices by a certain distance,
2. moving them with snapping to a separate target object,
3. scaling with snapping to a target,
4. scaling them down (in *Edit Mode*) by an appropriate factor or
5. scaling up by new size, then scaling down by reciprocal of old size (or vice versa).

First of all, no matter which method you choose, you have to do them in *Edit Mode* (press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch into *Edit Mode*).

### 1: Moving by a certain distance

The original wall has 265.3 m in X direction and you want to size it down to 75 m. That is a difference of
$$265.3-75=190.3$$
i.e. you need
$$\frac{190.3}{2}=95.15$$
on each side if you want to move the vertices evenly on each side. So select the vertices on the left border of the wall, to move them to the right they have to be moved 95.15 m in +X direction.

To do this, press <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>95.15</kbd> and then <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the action.

[image: move on x]

Another possibility would be to click into the *Transform* > *Median* > *X* field and instead of replacing the value, type <kbd>+95.15</kbd> behind it and press <kbd>Return</kbd>. You also could have replaced the value with a calculated new one, but Blender can do the maths for you.

[image: enter new value]

The best thing about this method is: Blender can do all the maths for you. It does not matter which way you enter it:

- $\text{old value }+95.15$
- $\text{old value }+190.3/2$
- $\text{old value }+(265.3-75)/2$

As long as it is mathematically correct (brackets where needed for example), Blender will give the correct result for the transformation.

[image: different formulas]

For the right side you repeat what you did for the left side, only this time you have to use the negative X direction by simply typing a minus before the value: <kbd>-92.15</kbd>.

Of course you do not have to make it half the size difference on each side, instead you could also move one side 100 m and the other 90.3 m, just as long as it sums up to 190.3 m.

### 2: Moving or scaling with snapping to a target object

To do this, add a new object (best might be a cube) which is 75 m wide in X direction. Then switch the wall to *Edit Mode* and select the vertices on the left side. Make sure you have the *Snap To* options set to *Vertex* and *Affect* > *Move* (and for method **3** later) *Scale* are enabled.

[image: snapping options]

Now press <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> to start moving the vertices towards the additional cube. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move the cursor towards the top or bottom left corner of the cube to make the vertices snap to a cube vertex and then left-click or <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the action. Repeat the same for the wall vertices on the right and the right side of the cube.

[image: move and snap]

### 3: Scaling with snapping to a target object

Instead of moving each sides separately, when the cube is exactly placed in the center of the left and right border of the wall you could also scale them down to the desired size.

To place the cube in the center of the wall borders you can select both sides in *Edit Mode*, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*. Adding a new cube will place it at the 3D cursor, i.e. in the center between the walls.

Back to the wall in *Edit Mode*, with both sides selected and the *Snap To* settings set like mentioned before under method **2**, press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> to scale them down in X direction, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move the cursor to the nearest cube corner to make the walls snap to one side of the cube. Then left-click or <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm.

[image: scaling evenly]

### 4: Scaling down by an appropriate factor

Since it is easy to calculate a ratio between two different values, you could simply divide the desired length by the original length to get the scaling factor. That is
$$\frac{75}{265.3}\approx0.2826988$$
which you can then simply enter when scaling on the X axis.

So select the outer vertices and type <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>.2826988</kbd> and then <kbd>Return</kbd>. Of course it is completely up to you how exact you want this value and how many decimals you need to have an acceptable approximation to the desired width.

[image: scaling by factor]

### 5: Scaling up by new size and down by reciprocal of old size

If scaling by an approximated value is not exact enough for you, you can again let Blender do the maths for you. Unfortunately it is not possible to enter a scaling value in the *Transform* sidepanel in *Edit Mode*, and scaling with <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> does not allow entering the formula <kbd>75 / 265.3</kbd> as a value directly.

Whenever you enter the forward slash key <kbd>/</kbd> while scaling, Blender switches to "reciprocal mode" I would call it. So whatever numbers you entered, Blender will put a <kbd>1/</kbd> in front of it (and it does not matter if you first enter numbers then slash or vice versa or even inbetween).

This means: if you wanted to enter the formula normally by typing <kbd>75</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>265.3</kbd>, this will be changed to <kbd>1/</kbd><kbd>75265.3</kbd>. In the same way both <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>75</kbd> and <kbd>75</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> will be switched to <kbd>1/</kbd><kbd>75</kbd>.

But still we can use those two values to get the new size, because
$$width\:\cdot\frac{75}{265.3}\equiv\:width\:\cdot 75\cdot\frac{1}{265.3}$$
and we just have to perform two scalings succesively.

To do this, you select the outer vertices of the wall and first scale them up by the new size with <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>75</kbd> and confirming the action. Now scale them down with the reciprocal of the old size by typing a slash before (or after) the value: <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>/265.3</kbd> (or <kbd>265.3/</kbd>) and confirming with <kbd>Return</kbd> afterwards.

[image: scale up by new size]

[image: scale down by recirpocal old size]